# How to run Protractor test in Eclipse? can we start server in eclipse?

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, protractor

I have installed protractor plugin's in eclipse but i am not sure how to run the test in eclipse. can some-one please help me in this.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459476/how-to-run-your-protractor-tests-in-eclipse?answertab=active#tab-top